# Joining two tables , one with parent child hierarchy and the output is giving more rows than table 1

Tags: sql, duplicates

```
   select b.top_lvl_itm_num,
    b.grp_lvl_itm_num,
    b.cmpnt_lvl_itm_num,
    b.lvl,
    b.grp_lvl_plt,
    b.cmpnt_lvl_plt ,
    a.sys_category from v_lttt_cost b 
    left join v_lttt_sys_category_map a on b.top_lvl_itm_num=a.top_lvl_itm_num and 
    b.grp_lvl_itm_num=b.grp_lvl_itm_num and b.cmpnt_lvl_itm_num=b.cmpnt_lvl_itm_num and b.lvl=a.lvl

    where b.grp_lvl_itm_num='MV' and 
    b.cmpnt_lvl_itm_num="ON1433' and 
    b.lvl=12 and 
    b.grp_lvl_plt='1110'
```

This is the code I am using . I should be getting back only 11 rows but is is giving me 121 rows. 11 rows is what the left table has .

Comment: your column name is not enough clear, please add your  create table script and sample data insert script. i guess you need `where a.top_lvl_itm_num is not null and ...`

Comment: Seems like there is a syntax error for the query, could you check please

Comment: I've used all the columns from table a as a filter and it still gives me 121. Table b is a recursive CTE I am using to build parent child relation ship . Table A has all the part numbers and I trying to fetch all the records from Table A and one column from table B

Comment: Why are you joining the columns from the same table ? is it needed ? probably that may be reason why you are getting that many rows

Comment: provide sample data . It will be easier to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

```
b.cmpnt_lvl_itm_num="ON1433'
```

Used here "ON1433' " '  ，There should be an error

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same alias name `b` in both sides of the join, it caused more data.

I have modified the query:

```
select b.top_lvl_itm_num,
    b.grp_lvl_itm_num,
    b.cmpnt_lvl_itm_num,
    b.lvl,
    b.grp_lvl_plt,
    b.cmpnt_lvl_plt ,
    a.sys_category 
from v_lttt_cost b 
left join v_lttt_sys_category_map a 
on b.top_lvl_itm_num=a.top_lvl_itm_num and 
   b.grp_lvl_itm_num=a.grp_lvl_itm_num and    
   b.cmpnt_lvl_itm_num=a.cmpnt_lvl_itm_num and 
   b.lvl=a.lvl
    where b.grp_lvl_itm_num='MV' and 
    b.cmpnt_lvl_itm_num='ON1433' and 
    b.lvl=12 and 
    b.grp_lvl_plt='1110'
```

**UPDATE**: From your comment, it appears the you have got data getting 11 times multiplied even after putting LEFT JOIN then, it means you have got many rows(in this case 11 rows) for the JOIN combination in the right table. If you are getting duplicates in your data, you can put `DISTINCT` clause to filter out the duplicates.

Comment: select   a.top_lvl_itm_num,
a.grp_lvl_itm_num,
a.cmpnt_lvl_itm_num,
 a.lvl,
 a.grp_lvl_plt,
 a.cmpnt_lvl_plt ,
 M.sys_category from V_LTTT_COST a



left join V_LTTT_SYS_CATEGORY_MAP M on  M.top_lvl_itm_num = a.top_lvl_itm_num and M.grp_lvl_itm_num=a.grp_lvl_itm_num
and a.cmpnt_lvl_itm_num=M.cmpnt_lvl_itm_num and a.lvl=M.lvl and a.grp_lvl_plt = m.grp_lvl_plt and 
 a.cmpnt_lvl_plt=m.cmpnt_lvl_plt

where a.top_lvl_itm_num='MV_D11T4_FUS' 
and a.lvl=12 
and  a.grp_lvl_plt='1110'
and  a.cmpnt_lvl_plt ='1110'
and a.grp_lvl_itm_num='0N1433'
and a.cmpnt_lvl_itm_num='0N1433';

Comment: MV_D11T4_FUS 0N1433 0N1433 12 1110 1110 HYDI
MV_D11T4_FUS 0N1433 0N1433 12 1110 1110 HYDI
MV_D11T4_FUS 0N1433 0N1433 12 1110 1110 HYDI
MV_D11T4_FUS 0N1433 0N1433 12 1110 1110 HYDI
MV_D11T4_FUS 0N1433 0N1433 12 1110 1110 HYDI
MV_D11T4_FUS 0N1433 0N1433 12 1110 1110 HYDI
MV_D11T4_FUS 0N1433 0N1433 12 1110 1110 HYDI
MV_D11T4_FUS 0N1433 0N1433 12 1110 1110 HYDI
MV_D11T4_FUS 0N1433 0N1433 12 1110 1110 HYDI
MV_D11T4_FUS 0N1433 0N1433 12 1110 1110 HYDI
MV_D11T4_FUS 0N1433 0N1433 12 1110 1110 PTN

Comment: This is what I should be seeing. The above data is coming back 11 times more

Comment: It means that you have got many rows in the right side table and so, the data is multiplying. It is exptected behaviour. Say you have id =1 in left table and there are 11 rows with id=1 in the right table then the record will be multiplied by 11 times

Comment: If you want to reduce the count apply DISTINCT Clause

Comment: If I use distinct I get only two rows for each sys category . Table V_LTTT_Cost has 11 rows with the filters in query and V_LTTT_sys_category_map has 11 rows with the same filters . I am not sure what I am  missing here

Comment: I would suggest you to first get minimum reproducible sample data and work on it. you can get better answers and easy to troubleshoot. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example